# how to put different distances between the items inside a **ListView.builder** depending on their score?

Tags: flutter, dart, timeline

I'm trying to display a list of contestants that are participating in a challenge and sort them by their score but other then that I'm trying to put **some actual distance between them** in the list where one can actually tell how far behind he actually is from the other contestant whether he is in **front or behind of him with their accumulated score**(you will find an example of what I'm trying to do down below), so far what I've done is displaying the list of the contestants with a **listview.builder** and returned a **TimelineTile()** ([timeline_tile](https://pub.dev/packages/timelinem_tile)) and the result is shown below, what I'm stuck right now is how to start/do the dynamic distance between each contestant depending on their score?

Any help is appreciated :D

My **ListView.builder**:

```
      body: Center(
        child: ListView.builder(
          shrinkWrap: true,
          itemCount: _contestants.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            var data = _contestants[index];
            bool isTeamOne = data.team == 'teamOne';
            bool isTeamTwo = data.team == 'teamTwo';
            return SizedBox(
              height: 100,
              width: 50,
              child: TimelineTile(
                alignment: TimelineAlign.center,
                endChild: isTeamOne
                    ? Align(
                        alignment: Alignment.centerLeft, child: _userCard(data))
                    : const Text(''),
                startChild: isTeamTwo
                    ? Align(
                        alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
                        child: _userCard(
                          data,
                        ))
                    : const Text(''),
                beforeLineStyle: const LineStyle(
                  color: Colors.brown,
                  thickness: 5,
                ),
                afterLineStyle: const LineStyle(
                  color: Colors.black,
                  thickness: 5,
                ),
                indicatorStyle: IndicatorStyle(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 0),
                  color: isTeamOne ? Colors.red : Colors.green,
                  indicatorXY: 0.5,
                  drawGap: true,
                ),
              ),
            );
          },
        ),
      ),

  Widget _userCard(ChallengeModel data) {
    return Card(
      elevation: 5,
      color: Colors.teal,
      child: Text(data.name),
    );
  }
```

My list of data:

```
  final List<ChallengeModel> _contestants = [
    ChallengeModel(
      id: 1,
      name: 'Team1',
      createdAt: 'createdAt',
      numeric: 4,
      team: 'teamOne',
      indicatorXY: 0.7,
    ),
    ChallengeModel(
      id: 2,
      name: 'Team2',
      createdAt: 'createdAt',
      numeric: 3,
      team: 'teamTwo',
      indicatorXY: 0.5,
    ),
    ChallengeModel(
      id: 3,
      name: 'Team1',
      createdAt: 'createdAt',
      numeric: 2,
      team: 'teamOne',
      indicatorXY: 0.3,
    ),
    ChallengeModel(
      id: 4,
      name: 'Team2',
      createdAt: 'createdAt',
      numeric: 3,
      team: 'teamTwo',
      indicatorXY: 0.6,
    ),
  ];
```

What I want to achieve: [image]

What I got so far:

[image]

**Update**

I tried another approach to put actual distance between the players/contestants on a challenge, what I did was by putting everything in a stack and draw a line with a **Container()** and removed the **TimeLineTile()** widget and added some **containers** as cards and dots to see where he is in the line, the way I move them up and down is by basically pushing the player/contestant from the bottom to the top, but this is leading to some other issues mainly the accuracy of the miles a player/contestant has and the actual moving of the container proportionally in the drawn line(which is the line of how much miles should a player/contestant accomplish)

My code so far with the **Stack()** solution:

```
    body: SingleChildScrollView(
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 0.0),
        child: Stack(
          alignment: AlignmentDirectional.bottomCenter,
          children: [
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 28.0),
              child: Container(
                height: 500,
                width: 20,
                color: Colors.red,
              ),
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 0.0),
              child: ListView.builder(
                shrinkWrap: true,
                itemCount: _contestants.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  var data = _contestants[index];
                  bool isTeamOne = data.team == 'teamOne';
                  bool isTeamTwo = data.team == 'teamTwo';
                  return Align(heightFactor: 0.01, child: _userCard(data));
                },
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );

  Widget _userCard(ChallengeModel data) {
    var isTeamOne = data.team == 'teamOne';
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 167.0),
      child: Container(
        margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: data.numeric),
        alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
        child: Row(
          mainAxisAlignment:
              isTeamOne ? MainAxisAlignment.end : MainAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
            isTeamOne
                ? const Icon(Icons.ac_unit_rounded)
                : Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 20.0),
                    child: Card(
                      elevation: 5,
                      color: Colors.teal,
                      child: Text(data.name),
                    ),
                  ),
            isTeamOne
                ? Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 20.0),
                    child: Card(
                      elevation: 5,
                      color: Colors.teal,
                      child: Text(data.name),
                    ),
                  )
                : Icon(Icons.ac_unit_rounded),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: What are you doing now to add distance between them?

Comment: Well I tried to add distance between them with the parameter **indicatorXY** but there were two problems with it, 1st: the card didn't move when the **indicator** moved through the axis and the 2nd: the indicator only accepts values from 0.0 to 1.0 and that it moves only in its restricted area which is the before&afterLine parameter.

Comment: Are you using Stack to build that UI of any plugin?

Comment: no I'm not, the code that I posted is all I have done as of now.

Comment: Check my answer if works for you.

Answer (score 1):

I think wrapping your **TimelineTile** into S**i**zedBox then `assigning` a `height` will be good option. Try below code :

```
Column(
        children: [
          SizedBox(
            height: 200,
            child: TimelineTile(
              alignment: TimelineAlign.center,
              startChild: Container(
                height: 50,
                child: Card(
                  color: Colors.lightBlueAccent,
                  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50)),
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10.0),
                    child: Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                      children: [
                        Text("59"),Text("Title"),
                        Icon(Icons.ac_unit)
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          SizedBox(
            height: 150,
            child: TimelineTile(
              alignment: TimelineAlign.center,
              endChild: Container(
                height: 50,
                child: Card(
                  color: Colors.lightBlueAccent,
                  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50)),
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10.0),
                    child: Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                      children: [
                        Text("59"),Text("Title"),
                        Icon(Icons.ac_unit)
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          SizedBox(
            height: 80,
            child: TimelineTile(
              alignment: TimelineAlign.center,
              endChild: Container(
                height: 50,
                child: Card(
                  color: Colors.lightBlueAccent,
                  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50)),
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10.0),
                    child: Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                      children: [
                        Text("59"),Text("Title"),
                        Icon(Icons.ac_unit)
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          SizedBox(
            height: 100,
            child: TimelineTile(lineXY: 0.0,
              alignment: TimelineAlign.center,
              endChild: SizedBox(
                height: 50,
                child: Card(
                  color: Colors.lightBlueAccent,
                  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50)),
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10.0),
                    child: Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                      children: [
                        Text("59"),Text("Title"),
                        Icon(Icons.ac_unit)
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      )
```

[image]

Comment: Would you mind putting some comments in the code and try to explain it why you did it this way? because I'm having a hard time understanding it.

Comment: Don't worry I haven't implemented much code just added the SizedBox so that you can have different height for each Timeline and a fixed height to the Container inside Timeline. I'm also attaching the result image

Comment: I tried your solution and it works perfectly if it is static but what I'm looking for is a dynamic solution because If i just change the height of the **SizedBox()** dynamically with data that I get from the list which in my case is **data.numeric** then the height will start from 0 and it will go to until 100 and every height under 50 is just not acceptable in my case, in a few minutes I will update my question to show what I got so far with another alternative aka **Stack()**

Comment: I updated the question with what I got so far with the **Stack()** approach please have a look, any help is appreciated :D.

Comment: This solution doesn't work for you? When using Stack you also have to provide coordinates to set position.

Comment: Yes because every player/contestant has to start from 0 meaning their score and if the height of the **SizedBox** is changed dynamically and the score is 0 then the **TimeLineTile** wouldn’t show at all thats why this wouldn’t work in my case as per the **Stack()** approach it removes this problem but brings other problems which I've mentioned in the question.

Comment: How will you calculate the height?

Comment: The height should be calculated with the score that a player/contestant has accumulated, so basically if a player/contestant runs 2km his/her score will be 2 and the height that it should be is 2

Comment: Still stuck? or got that you are looking for?

Comment: Nope I'm still stuck on it, because as I've mentioned in the updated question the accuracy with the **Stack()** approach is difficult because on both sides I will have to put a ruler to see where the player/contestant is within the challenge and accuracy is key for that and I have no idea how to resolve this, any help would be appreciated :D